# Removing Item at index from a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

```
   public class LinkedList
   {
  private Node head;
  private Node tail;
  private int numberOfElements;

  public LinkedList()
  {
      head = null;
      tail = null;
      this.numberOfElements = 0;
  }

  public int length()
  {
      return this.numberOfElements;
  }

  public void removeFront()
  {
      Node currNode = head;
      head = head.getNextNode();
      currNode.setNextNode(null);
      this.numberOfElements--;  
  }

  public void removeLast()
  {
      this.tail = this.tail.prev;

  }

  public void removeAtIndex(int index) throws AmishException 
  {
     if (index == 0) {
           Node q = head;
           head = q.getNextNode();
      }
      else if ((index > numberOfElements - 1) || (index < 0)) 
           System.out.println("Index out bounds.");
      else {
        Node currNode = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {

            currNode = currNode.getNextNode();
        }
        Node temp = currNode;
        currNode = temp.getPrevNode();
        currNode.setNextNode(temp.getNextNode());
        temp = null;
        numberOfElements--;
    }




  }
```

Node -

```
 public class Node 
 {
private int payload;
private Node nextNode;
public Node prev;
public Node previous;
public Node next;

public Node(int payload)
{
    this.payload = payload;
    nextNode = null;
}

public Node getNextNode()
{
    return this.nextNode;

}

public Node getPrevNode()
{
    return this.getPrevNode();
}
public void setNextNode(Node n)
{
    this.nextNode = n;
}

public void display()
{
     System.out.print("(" + super.toString() + " : " + this.payload + ")");
     if(this.nextNode != null)
     {
         System.out.print(" -> ");
         this.nextNode.display();
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("");
     }
}

public String toString()
{
    return "" + super.toString() + " : " + this.payload;
}

public void setPrevNode(Node n) 
{

        previous = n;


}




  }
```

Driver -

```
    public class Driver 
     {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
      {
          LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
          ll.addFront(7);
          ll.addFront(5);
          ll.addEnd(13);
          ll.addEnd(27);
          ll.addFront(2);
          ll.addAtIndex(1, 0);
          ll.addAtIndex(12, 6);
          ll.addAtIndex(9, 2);
          ll.addAtIndex(11, 2);

          //ll.removeFront();

          //ll.removeLast();

          ll.removeAtIndex(1);



          for(int i = 0; i < ll.length(); i++)
          {
              System.out.println(ll.get(i));
          }


       }    
   }
```

I got what I need to remove the head's index, but how to do anything else is beyond me.
I have the methods to remove the head and the tail now I just need to know how to remove at an index just Like if I were to add at an index.

Comment: If you need to remove at an index, you need to _get_ to that index.

Comment: I have a method that does that, so if I do Node currNode = currNode.get(index); it gets there but after that I don't know how to hook everything up

Comment: Conceptually, do you know how to remove a node from a doubly linked list? (I'm assuming you have a doubly linked list.)

Comment: yes I have two methods one to remove from the front and tail but that's all right now..

Comment: Out of curiosity, and completely off-topic, what the heck is an `AmishException`?

Comment: it's a joke between the instructor and the class, he wanted us to make our own exception and he finds the amish hilarious for some reason.

Comment: That doesn't tell me you know how to remove a node in the middle of a linked list. Revisit your notes if you don't. The implementation follows that exactly.

Comment: You have to add Node at index and push all the nodes down until it reaches to tail's index

Comment: I added in some code I tried, but now i need a set previous node method and everytime I try to make one like my set next node method the program breaks. any suggestions?

Comment: I know for this part I need to remove the node at the index, and hook the previous and next nodes together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, completely editing this answer. I took your code and went from that. There were some issues with your Node class, check out mine. I created a barebones Node class, add the any other functionality you may need/want. For the LinkedList class, I created a simple add method that adds to the end of the list. Use this as a prototype for your other adds. Everything right now is working and I put some println's to help you see where the program is at. I highly recommend using a debugger. Also note that this is a doubly linked list.

Linked List

```
public class LinkedList {
  private Node head;
  private Node tail;
  private int numberOfElements;

  public LinkedList()
  {
      head = null;
      tail = null;
      numberOfElements = 0;
  }

  public int length()
  {
      return numberOfElements;
  }

  public void removeAtIndex(int index) 
  {
     if (index == 0) {
           Node q = head;
           head = q.getNextNode();
           numberOfElements--;
      }
      else if ((index > numberOfElements - 1) || (index < 0)) 
           System.out.println("Index out of bounds.");
      else {
        Node currNode = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            //Node p = currNode;
            System.out.println("At this payload " + currNode.getPayload());
            currNode = currNode.getNextNode();
            System.out.println("Now at this payload " + currNode.getPayload());
        }
        Node temp = currNode;
        System.out.println("Removing the node with payload " + temp.getPayload()); 
        currNode = temp.getPrevNode();
        currNode.setNextNode(temp.getNextNode());
        temp = null;
        numberOfElements--;
    }

  }

  public void add(int num) {
      Node newNode = new Node(num);
      newNode.setNextNode(null);
      if (numberOfElements == 0) {
          newNode.setPrevNode(null);
          head = newNode;
          tail = newNode;
        }
      else if (numberOfElements == 1) {
          head.setNextNode(newNode);
          tail = newNode;
          tail.setPrevNode(head);
        }
      else {
        newNode.setPrevNode(tail);
        tail.setNextNode(newNode);
        tail = newNode;
      }
      System.out.println("Inserted " + num + " into the linked list");
     numberOfElements++;
    }

  public void printList() {
      Node temp = head;
      while (temp != null) {
          System.out.println("Node with payload " + temp.getPayload());
          temp = temp.getNextNode();
        }
    }


  }
```

Node

```
public class Node {
    private int payload;
    private Node next;
    private Node prev;

    public Node(int payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
        prev = null;
        next = null;
    }

    public Node getNextNode() {
        return next;
    }

    public Node getPrevNode() {
        return prev;
    }

    public void setNextNode(Node n) {
        next = n;
    }

    public void setPrevNode(Node n) {
        prev = n;
    }

    public int getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

}
```

Driver

```
public class Driver {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
          ll.add(7);
          ll.add(5);
          ll.add(13);
          ll.add(27);
          ll.add(2);
          ll.printList();
          ll.removeAtIndex(3);
          ll.printList();
      }
}
```

Comment: Ok I think this will work but for some reason the while loop is breaking the program not sure why

Comment: In your removeAtIndex method, first check that the index passed is within the list bounds. So index > 0 and index <= numberOfElements. Then check if index == 1, if true, call removeFront(). Then else if index == numberOfElements, call removeLast(). Then else you are within the bounds of the list, set the counter, currNode, nextNode, and begin iterating through the while loop.

Comment: How exactly is is breaking the program?

Comment: I'm using the above solution and it's breaking when it tries to get the previous node

Comment: Hmm, I didn't use a previous pointer. Is your list doubly-linked? My example moves through the list with two pointers. nextNode will arrive on the node to delete and currNode will arrive on the node before it, so you don't lose the rest of the linked list.

Comment: it is doubly linked yes so i don't know whats happening

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code you are currently trying.

Comment: I added in all my code, everything there is what i currently have \

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

got this error at  currNode.setNextNode() = temp.getNextNode();

Comment: I got rid of the setnextnode on currnode. but when I run it and change the index in driver it just removes the 7 from the list for some reason..

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be inside the (), not an assignment statement. I edited the code above.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at LinkedList.removeAtIndex(LinkedList.java:50)
 at Driver.main(Driver.java:22)

Comment: now i'm getting this error when I set the index in driver to anything other than 0

Comment: Alright, completely overhauled the answer. Everything posted is tested and working. Hopefully it helps you out. Use that as a guide to implementing your other linked list and node methods.